# Using docker container inside npm package

Tags: docker, npm, neo4j

I'm implementing TypeScript compiler API addon as standalone `npm` package which is supposed to traverse TypeScript code and offload dependencies graph into `neo4j` database for further graph analysis with `Apoc` API.

Is it even possible to use third-party software packed as `Docker` container from within `npm` package? What's the best practice in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a network connection to a database or other process running in a container, in the same way you could as if it were running directly on the host or if it were a different host.  For Neo4j it looks like there are [several required connection options](https://neo4j.com/docs/javascript-manual/current/client-applications/#js-driver-connection-uris) such as the URL of some server and authentication information, but as far as a client application is concerned it doesn't matter at all if the database is running in Docker or somewhere else.

If the database was running in a container on the same system, and the TypeScript compiler isn't running in a container too, and you're not using Docker Toolbox or another VM-based Docker implementation, then you can *probably* connect to `neo4j://localhost:7687`; that would require the database to have been started with a `docker run -p 7687:7687` or similar option to publish the port.  That could be a reasonable default value for something that could be configured with an environment variable or a config-file setting.

Your extension library couldn't start the database itself.  If you can start a Docker container then you can use bind-mounts and other container options to root the entire host, and in many environments this reasonably requires `sudo` permissions.

Comment: So I basically cannot embrace `neo4j` functionality into `npm` package and have to require user to setup `neo4j` database up'n'running on his/her own prior to invoking my TypeScript addon?

Comment: You might consider a lighter-weight database like SQLite that doesn't require a dedicated server process.

Comment: The point is to structure data in form of a graph and `neo4j` fits perfectly for that. So, I guess what I initially wanted is impossible, which is ok and I might just ship `docker-compose` file and some to setup `neo4j` on client side.